# How to import csv file to QuestDb from Python?

Tags: python, questdb

I'm trying to import file to Questdb as REST csv upload. My code looks like

```py
import requests
with open('..\data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:9000/imp?name=weekly3', files={'data.csv': f})
    print(r.text)
```

However I get back

`{"status":"invalid value in 'Content-Disposition' multipart header"}`

I do not see anything wrong with Content-Disposition when I dump the request

```
POST http://localhost:9000/imp?name=weekly3
Content-Length: 197
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=23ef3f7581b79898155acd5567e0b455
--23ef3f7581b79898155acd5567e0b455
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data.csv"; filename="data.csv"
C:\Users\allnau\Downloads\data.csv
--23ef3f7581b79898155acd5567e0b455--
```

Answer (score 1):

In your files dictionary csv should be under **data** key.

```py
import requests
with open('..\data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:9000/imp?name=weekly3', files={'data': f})
```

As per curl [examples](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/rest), QuestDb accepts **data** and **schema** form parts at ?imp endpoint

Comment: It should be a `r'...'` string for the path, and the POST should announce the file's encoding.